# Error happening in login page. It's not getting authenticated with the registered user

Tags: php, swift3, xampp, xcode8

I am trying to do login authentication using Alamofire and PHP as a web service and MySQL.

When I register the users and hit the register button, the values will be stored in the database, but when I try to login with user name and password, it will not authenticate, though I get a response message as success in the console. It won't redirect to the next page.

Any help? I have also commented with the other technique which I used.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // let URL_USER_REGISTER = "http://mymacipaddress/Mylogin/v1/login.php"

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldUsername: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!

    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        /*   if (textFieldUsername.text == "admin" && textFieldPassword.text == "admin")
         {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
         }
         else
         {
         labelMessage.text = "incorrect username and password"
         }

         */

        let user = "user"
        let password = "password"

        Alamofire.request("http://mymacipaddress/Mylogin/v1/login.php")
            .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
                print(response.response as Any) // HTTP URL response
                print(response.data as Any)     // server data
                print(response.result)

                if let _ = response.result.value {

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)

                }
                else
                {
                    self.labelMessage.text = "incorrect"
                }
        }
    }


    /*
     let user = "user"
     let password = "password"

     var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]

     if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
     headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
     }

     Alamofire.request("http://mymacipaddress/Mylogin/v1/login.php", headers: headers)
     .responseJSON { response in
     debugPrint(response)
     //         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
     self.labelMessage.text = "correct"

     }
     */


    /*
     let user = "user"
     let password = "password"

     let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .forSession)

     Alamofire.request("http://mymacipaddress/Mylogin/v1/login.php/\(user)/\(password)")
     .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
     .responseJSON { response in
     debugPrint(response)
     self.labelMessage.text = "correct"
     }



     }

     */

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```